# Running 3rd party applications in the browser

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, sandbox, browser-security

I'm currently designing the frontend for a large app. The plan is to have a master app that manages child apps and the user can add more apps to their dashboard from an app store, all in JavaScript in the browser. The problem is sandboxing, basically, I don't want `appX` to be able to steal `appY`'s data (via the DOM or otherwise). I know of Google Caja though currently I'm leaning towards an iframe running on a different domain (with a very fancy nginx config to allow apps to share APIs). Would this work ? Are there any alternatives (to running 3rd party applications in the context of the browser) ?